# How generate Uniform Noise

Tags: matlab, image-processing, noise, digital, uniform

I have a question, how can I generate uniform noise using its general equation in the MatLab
and apply it to a specific image, with a simplified explanation of the code if possible.
[General Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlY3H.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should try the `rand()` command which outputs a realization of a uniform distribution on `[0, 1]`. To get the general distribution, you can do the manipulation `((b - a) * rand() + a`.